# phpsh not found

Tags: php, macos, phpsh

I am having problems with phpsh after I upgraded to mountain lion

I installed php5.4 with the php-osx and got that playing nice with mysql.

So when I followed the directions to install phpsh and got the `phpsh not found` in ZSH shell, It didn't make any sense? I had it running before I upgraded.

Also `php -a` is doing nothing, just hangs?

I don't know anything about python but when I run where python I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I know that's a mouthful but can someone help?

Cheers

Comment: What does running `php --version` produce? You should at least get the version and build information.

Comment: PHP 5.4.9 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2012 17:56:22)and which php returns /usr/local/php5/bin/php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding
sudo chown -R "whoami" /usr/local